# Regex Find Name in Fixed Length Records

Tags: regex

I have this flat file and I want to make sure I only display records where the first name is Andrew

```
00012 Andrew Carter
02349 John Smith
20089 Charlotte Andrew
```

Each line contains, in order, three fields: five-digit employee number, first name, and last name. Each field is delimited by a space.

Comment: Are you trying to capture the information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to find all lines that match the following pattern:

```
\d+\sAndrew.+
```

Or, as @Sam Sullivan points out, you could also specify the number of digits:

```
\d{5}\sAndrew.+
```

If you have set your regex options to allow the dot to match newline characters, you could use `[^\n]+` instead of the final `.+`, as @Sam Sullivan also points out. But as @Casimir et Hippolyte notes, by default the dot will not match newline characters.

Comment: Slightly tweaked: `\d{5}\sAndrew[^\n]+`

Comment: @SamSullivan: since the dot, by default, doesn't match newlines, this replacement is useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
([0-9]{5})\s(Andrew)\s([A-Za-z\s.,-]{1,})
```

Each parenthesis will capture the three pieces of information.

`00012`, `Andrew`, `Carter`

This requires 5 numeric, a space, the name Andrew (case sensitive), another space, and then whatever the last name is, including surnames and suffixes.

The third capture is looking for a capital letter a through z, or a lower case letter a-z, a space, a period, comma, or dash

So "Carter-Smith, Jr. M.D." is a valid last name.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this is a case where tools can be your friend.
Check out
expresso: "http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm"
It's great for design and testing of regexes
Also there is
RegexCoach: http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/
Which actually lets you step RegExs like normal code

On to your question though:
Begin line: `^`
Five digits: `\d\d\d\d\d`
Space: `\w`
Name: `Andrew`
Space: `\w`
LastName: `[A-Za-z]+`
End: `$`

So:
`^\d\d\d\d\d\wAndrew\w[A-Za-z]+$`

Disclaimer - not tested, but pretty confident :)

Comment: I thought the {Count} syntax wasn't standard syntax and was parser specific?

Comment: What if my last name is Smith-Lincoln